# Asp.net 3.5 - Custom non-fatal exception

Tags: asp.net, exception

Custom non-fatal exception derive from which class in asp.net 3.5?

Comment: What is a fatal and a non-fatal exception for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a custom exception (whether it's fatal or not) you would start by looking at extending from the System.Exception class.  However, there is a pretty verbose hierarchy of exception classes already in the .NET framework.  I would advise reviewing them before implementing your own custom exception class.  Also, if your custom exception is inherently about something specific (like IO for example) you should consider extending from the most appropriate exception in that case.